# Sending a POST request with PHPUnit

Tags: php, symfony, post, tdd, phpunit

I have a symfony website, and Im trying to do some unit testing. I have this kind of test where I try to submit something:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\AcmeBundle\Tests\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class HomeControllerTest extends WebTestCase {

    public function testrandomeThings() {

        $client = static::createClient();
        $crawler = $client->request(
            'POST',
            '/',
            array(
                "shopNumber"        => 0099,
                "cardNumber"        => 231,
                "cardPIN"           => "adasd"),
            array(),
            array());
        }
```

but I dont think that the data Im sending is being received in the controler:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {

        var_dump($_POST);
        die;
        return $this->render('AcmeBundle:Home:index.html.twig');
    }

}
```

the `var_dump` is actually returning me an empty array.

What am I missing to send information through my POST request?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$_POST` is a variable filled by PHP and the symfony request is only created from this globals if called directly over http. The symfony crawler doesn't make a real request, it creates a request from the parameters supplied in your `$client->request` and executes it. You need to access this stuff via the [`Request`](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html) object. Never use `$_POST`, `$_GET`, etc. directly.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class HomeController extends CoralBaseController
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {

        var_dump($request->request->all());
        die;
        return $this->render('CoralWalletBundle:Home:index.html.twig');
    }

}
```

use `$request->request->all()` to get all POST parameters in an array. To get only a specific parameter you can use `$request->request->get('my_param')`. If you ever need to acces GET parameters you can use `$request->query->get('my_param')`, but better set query parameters already in the routing pattern.

Answer (score 7):

I think you're trying to do this:

```
$client = static::createClient();
    $client->request($method, $url, [], [], [], json_encode($content));
    $this->assertEquals(
        200,
        $client->getResponse()
            ->getStatusCode()
    );
```

You're putting your data (content) in as the params array but you want to put it in as the raw body content which is a JSON encoded string.