# WebTestCase Phpunit send raw data not working

Tags: phpunit, file-get-contents, raw-data

I try to send raw data in my WebTestCase in PhpUnit and it doesn't work :

```
$jsonEvent = '{
      "type": "invoice.payment_succeeded",
}';
$this->client->request(
    'POST',
    '/api/v1/stripe/webhook',
    [],
    [],
    ['CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'],
    $jsonEvent
);
```

and i try to get data like this :

```
$input = file_get_contents("php://input");
var_dump($input);
```

But `$input` is empty

Not sure but perhaps it's not possible to get content input like that in webtestcase ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are using **Symfony** s **WebTestCase**. If this is the case, then first of all, remove the invalid comma from your json:

```
$jsonEvent = '{
  "type": "invoice.payment_succeeded"
}';
```

Second, I assume you are creating the client this way:

```
$this->client = static::createClient();
```

If this is the case, then the issue is the **request** method is **not doing an http request**, but it is finding the controller and action(internally using **"Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver"**) and calls it passing the parameters, content and headers set in **request method** to the appropriate symfony objects.

That is the reason you cannot use:

```
$input = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

as you are really running the same script.

To get the post body in your action, one way to do it is:

```
public function myAction(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->getContent();
```

**References & examples**

1. [Symfony working with client](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#working-with-the-test-client)
2. [Symfony client error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900890/sending-a-post-request-with-phpunit)